# HTML5 Range Input Reload

Tags: javascript, html, range

I am developing an online survey which uses the Range input type. So far I have managed to send the range value to an output display above the range slider, and to fill a textbox with the range value also.

However I am not having much luck when it comes to reloading the value from the checkbox for some reason. Ideally, I would also like this reloaded value to be pushed to provide the value for the range input as well.

The code is as follows:

```js
function vasOutputUpdate(val) {
  var val = document.getElementById('selectVAS').value;
  document.getElementById('vasOutput').value = val;
  document.getElementById('vasStored').value = val;
}
function reloadVAS() {
  var vas = document.getElementById('vasStored').value;
  if (vas == "") {
    vas = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('selectVAS').value = vas;
  } 
}
reloadVAS();
```

```css
#selectVAS {
  width: 378px;
}
#vasStored {
  width: 50px
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="selectVAS" name="selectVAS" min="0" max="10" step="0.5" oninput="vasOutputUpdate(this.value);" />
<output for="selectVAS" id="vasOutput">5</output>
<input type="text" id="vasStored" />
```

Can anyone see any errors in my code, or know of a solution to this issue? I am very new to this so I imagine it is something quite obvious..

Comment: The code works. You're doing something else wrong. Maybe try using this: `<input type="text" id="vasStored" style="width:50px" value="2">` to see if your function works in your application context.

Comment: Which checkbox are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, i meant to say textbox

Comment: @f.ardelian I just tried that and the issue does not seem to be on the reload end, as giving a discrete value to vasStored will make the Range slider load at 2. Is it possible that the problem lies in the `oninput="vasOutputUpdate(this.value);"` ? And specifically, how it interacts with the `vasOutputUpdate( )` function?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it well, you want something like

```js
var range = document.getElementById('selectVAS'),
    output = document.getElementById('vasOutput'),
    text = document.getElementById('vasStored');
(range.oninput = text.oninput = function() {
  range.value = text.value = output.value = this.value;
}).call(range);
```

```css
#selectVAS {
  width: 378px;
}
#vasStored {
  width: 50px
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="selectVAS" name="selectVAS" min="0" max="10" step="0.5" />
<output for="selectVAS" id="vasOutput">5</output>
<input type="text" id="vasStored" />
```

Comment: right, i am looking to store the value from the range in a text box essentially, which for some reason seems to be a problem. I am not exactly sure how oninput works but it seems that it is only storing a transient value? rather than a "hard" value.. when i try to push the value from the vasStored textbox nothing happens...

Comment: @RoryLattimer What is a "hard" value? Can you link a fiddle showing your problem?

Comment: sorry about the ambiguity, the problem is I am working within an electronic medical record. I think the problem is with the way they store data to be reloaded. we are merely instructed to store it in textboxes, which has worked up until now.. for some reason there is something different about the range input that is tripping me up